# Minimum SIMD vector width data type

Tags: c, vectorization, hardware, intel, simd

**I am trying to make sense of how much stuff I  can pack into vector hardware**. Taking for example an Intel AVX-512 capable piece of hardware I can fit either 8 doubles (64-bit) or 16 singles (32-bit) into my vector. However, if I am running on a 64-bit machine, then it is likely my default pointer size is 64-bit. Hence, if I want to de-reference a pointer (or just access and array using the array syntax) then this would require a 64-bit integer operation. This seems to suggest to me that on a 64-bit machine the minimum partitioning I can have would be 64-bit data types.

Consider then the MWE I have below, where I would hope the compiler would see I am only handling 32-bit objects (or smaller). Given I would anticipate the reduction/calculation (supposing I was doing something more computationally intensive and less bandwidth limited) to be done in half the time if I could partition the vector into 32-bit data types over using the 64-bit data types.

- Is there a way to query the granularity of the vector partitioning that the compiler has used? (Avoiding digging through the resulting assembly).
- On a 64-bit machine, how is the vector partitioned into data types less than 64-bit if a 64-bit memory address is assumed?

> It seems to me that if I have vector registers and I want to do vector operations then if I require `n` vector registers, where each register is split into data types of `m`-bits, then any section of code I wish to vectorise cannot use data-types larger than `m`. (?)

**MWE**

Compiled using `icc` 18.0.0 with `-mkl -O2 -qopenmp -qopt-report` where the optimisation report verifies the for loop vectorised.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int a[N];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) a[i] = i;
    unsigned int z[N];
    unsigned int *b = a;
    printf("Sizes (Bytes)\n");
    printf("Pointer      = %d\n", sizeof(b));
    printf("Unsigned int = %d\n", sizeof(*b));
    printf("Array        = %d\n\n", sizeof(a));

    unsigned int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        z[i] = 4 * a[i];
        unsigned int squares = a[i] * a[i]; // Possibly some more complex sequence of operations.
        sum += squares;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i += N/4) printf("z[%d] = %d\n", i, z[i]);
    printf("\nsum  = %d\n", sum);    
}
```

Output on my machine being:

```
Sizes (Bytes)
Pointer      = 8
Unsigned int = 4
Array        = 4096

z[0] = 0
z[256] = 1024
z[512] = 2048
z[768] = 3072

sum  = 357389824
```

Comment: Why does every type have to be at least as big as a pointer?

Comment: The width of the datatype in the SIMD vector has nothing to do with pointer size unless you're doing something involving gathers or scatters.

Comment: On x86, there are lots of SIMD instructions that operate on byte elements.  That's the minimum; there aren't any that operate on nibbles.  See all the `p...b` instructions in http://felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html.  Like `pshufb`: a byte-granularity shuffle that takes the shuffle-control from a register.  You can use it to do 16 lookups in parallel from a 16-element table, or to rearrange bytes in a vector any way you want.  Or `paddb`: add packed (integer) bytes, with no carry between bytes.

Answer (score 5):

> This seems to suggest to me that on a 64-bit machine the minimum partitioning I can have would be 64-bit data types.

This assumption is wrong.

To illustrate with an (awkward) analogy, the length of a postal address (in symbols) does not correlate with the size of a house. The width of a pointer does not correlate with size of data it references.

There is a *lower* bound of how small piece of data can be addressed on a given type of hardware. It's called *byte* (8 bits a.k.a. *octet* on modern machines, but it can also be 10 or 6 bits like on ancient generations). There is typically no *higher* bound, however. In Intel 64, as one example, XSAVE family of instructions references a memory block that is nearly 4 kbyte long, with the same 32/64 bit pointers.

> Taking for example an Intel AVX-512 capable piece of hardware I can fit either 8 doubles (64-bit) or 16 singles (32-bit) into my vector.

Or you can fit 32 half-floats (16-bit) or 64 bytes. Not sure if there are AVX-512 instructions operating on nibbles (4 bit chunks).

> Is there a way to query the granularity of the vector partitioning that the compiler has used? (Avoiding digging through the resulting assembly).

Again, the lower bound for compiler's choice is dictated by width of chosen data types in your program. If you use `int`, the granularity will be at least `sizeof(int)` bytes, if `long` — `sizeof(long)` etc. It is unlikely that a type wider than necessary will be used, because it would cause semantical differences of machine instructions that should be accounted for. For example, if a compiler, for unknown reasons, chooses to use a SIMD vector partitioned into `uint64_t` chunks to operate on a vector of `uint32_t` chunks, then it would have to hide differences in overflow behavior, and that would incur performance penalty.

I do not know if there are OMP pragmas to query for such information. It is unlikely, given that the same binary may have multiple code paths chosen dynamically at runtime (program's startup, so called dispatching used by Intel compiler at least), so the compile-time querying is out of the question, and I cannot see much use in runtime querying.

> On a 64-bit machine, how is the vector partitioned into data types less than 64-bit if a 64-bit memory address is assumed?

There are simply machine instructions that interpret the same SIMD registers differently. In Intel 64, as an example there are all sorts of them (examples taken from recent Intel Software Development Manual):

- VDBPSADBW—Double Block Packed Sum-Absolute-Differences (SAD) on **Unsigned Bytes** (8-bit)
- VCVTPH2PS — Convert **16-bit** FP values to Single-Precision FP values
- VCVTPS2UDQ—Convert Packed **Single-Precision** (32-bit) Floating-Point Values to Packed Unsigned Doubleword Integer Values
- VCVTQQ2PD—Convert Packed **Quadword** (64-bit) Integers to Packed Double-Precision Floating-Point Values

Comment: There are no nibble-element instructions even in AVX512.  x86 has [`DAA` to adjust the result of a packed-BCD add](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/DAA.html), but that uses a single-bit flag (`AF`), so it's not even really [SWAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR).  It *only* works for 2 BCD digits in AL, not for 4 in AX.  AVX512 has lots of crazy stuff, like [`VPMULTISHIFTQB`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPMULTISHIFTQB.html), but that's unaligned shifts within qword elements.

Comment: Why pick the AVX512BW-only [`VDBPSADBW`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VDBPSADBW) instead of the simpler [`vpsadbw`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PSADBW) which does a SAD of unsigned-byte differences within each 64-bit element.  Or something simple like `paddb`: add byte elements :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, a strange choice of examples. I was, however, sleepy and by the end of writing the answer I needed to attend to other matters; and now I cannot explain that list (-%

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to query the granularity of the vector partitioning
>   that the compiler has used? (Avoiding digging through the resulting
>   assembly).

I think the best answer to your question is: "learn what is your Vector Length from opt-report or from the tool like Vectorization Advisor".

There are several kinds and several possible definitions for VL:

- When vectorizing, Compiler chooses optimal **"Vector Length" (VL)**. Let's call it "compiler-defined loop VL". *Loop's* VL can be defined as a number of scalar iterations "packed into" resultant vector operation. So in simple non-FMA DP AVX-512 case VL is frequently equal to 4.
- VL can be also defined not for the loop, but for instruction (or
  somehow for instruction data operand), however "optimal" or "current"
  *per-instruction* VL may significantly differ from resultant loop's VL.
- You may also think of another metric, which is Hardware-defined loop
  (or instruction) VL.

Number of data elements which could be put into the single vector register, having in mind target ISA, precision etc. - is pretty much equal to Hardware-defined per-instruction VL.
Compiler-defined per-loop VL may frequently be higher or lower than "dominating" per-instruction hardware-defined VL. This is especially true for the loops with mixture of different data types or with loops additionally optimized for the micro-architecture, using techniques like register splitting (not spilling) or multi-pumping.

To know VL of your loop use -qopt-report flag when re-compiling your code with Intel Compiler.

To know compiler-defined and hardware-defined VL (not only for Intel Compiler) for your loops and instructions, along with time metrics, stride, binary ISA static anlysis (and even assembly if you'll need it eventually), FLOPS and AVX instruction mix data - use Intel Advisor (Survey analysis): [image]

Comment: Are you talking about AVX-512 but using only YMM registers to avoid lowering the max turbo?  Some compilers don't automatically auto-vectorize with ZMM registers, preferring YMM even if ZMM is available, because it can slow the *rest* of the program down to use ZMM instructions for one loop that turns out not to be important overall.  Anyway, 8 `double`s fit in a ZMM 512-bit vector, or 4 `double`s in a YMM 256-bit vector.

Comment: You are exactly right that on SKX compilers may prefer YMM code generation. Howevever it is not what I took in mind (and screen-shot is  taken on KNL). What I said instead is that, considering e.g.  AVX(1) Double Precision code, you could easily get Compiler_VL =2, Compiler_VL =8 and even Compiler_VL = 16. One example is a loop containing combination of Single Precision and Double Precision. Another example is register splitting for SNB. Third example is multi-pumping (kind of micro-unrolling). And of course non-default VL could be also requested by user explicitely via OMP4.x SIMD.